# Insert a text at the beginning of a file + stdout, stderr

Tags: bash, unix, ed

I have function "backup", and output for this function from the console is also redirected to a file, and it's done as follows:

```
backup > >(tee -a ./log.txt) 2>&1
```

it works, but I want to add new output data to the beginning of a file, and looks like for my case wisely use `ed` (not `sed`), and I doing it in the following way:

```
ed -s log.txt < <(printf '%s\n' 1i "$(backup)" . wq)
```

And in this case, I don't know how to implement the output to the console and the file at once (as it happens in my first case). Can somebody give me a hint of implementation?

Comment: Something’s not right in your example. The first command line uses the `backup` function for writing log.txt while the second command line uses `backup` to read log.txt.

Comment: Note that in general, writing data to the beginning of a file *requires rewriting the entire file from the beginning*, which is what `sed` or `ed` do when you ask them to make in-place changes. It's thus a slow/expensive operation and requires enough storage to have two copies, at least temporarily. It's better to avoid the need, wherever possible.

Comment: (A conventional UNIX filesystem lets you add data to the *end* of a file cheaply, or change content in-place by replacing N bytes at any position you choose with a different N bytes, but not to *insert new content* or to replace an old string with a new string of a different length).

Comment: Anyhow, the cheap/simple/slow thing is `cat - log.txt < <(...command that generates text to prepend...) >log.txt.new && mv log.txt.new log`. Any command you do with `ed`, `sed -i`, etc will effectively be the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly - you are trying to pre-pend the output of the backup command to the start of the log.txt file.  Moreover, you are trying to see  the backup output on the console.

Try this:

```
{
  backup 2>&1 | tee /dev/tty
  cat log.txt
} > log.txt.new
mv log.txt.new log.txt
```

Edit:

Here's a version of the code that follows Charles Duffy's suggestion:

```
cat <( backup 2>&1 | tee /dev/tty ) log.txt > log.txt.new && mv log.txt.new log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert a text to the beginning of every line of a file:

```
sed 's/^/MYTEXT /' path_to_file > path_to_file
```

Insert a text to the beginning of every stdout line:

```
COMMAND | sed 's/^/MYTEXT /'
```